# Compiling 3.2 Antlr grammar with gradle

Tags: antlr, gradle

I'm trying to compile my antlr grammar with gradle. I'm very new to gradle, so am having trouble working out how to fix the issue.

I think it's trying to use the 2.7 antlr to compile (as I've seen a few other people reporting similar errors when using wrong version), and hence throwing errors.

How can I:

1. Show what version of Antlr gradle is trying to use?
2. Get gradle to compile properly?

Here's my grammar:

```
grammar Test;

options {
  language = Java;
}

rule: ;
```

Here's my gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'antlr'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    antlr 'org.antlr:antlr:3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Here's the output trying to compile:

```
$ gradle compileJava
:generateGrammarSource
/home/admin/workspace/BuildTools/src/main/antlr/Test.g:1:1: unexpected token: grammar
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 2.458 secs
```

**EDIT:**

Seems Antlr3 isn't supported directly in gradle yet.

There's a [pull request to add antlr3 support](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/69) to gradle that's [discussed here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Antlr-v3-plugin-td5605784.html).

Here's [another version of including support for Antlr3](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/combining-gradle-with-antlr3.html) manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not very knowledgeable with Gradle myself, but `generateGrammarSource` uses ANTLR 2.7.x (not sure which exact version) because if I use it on a 2.7 grammar, the .java files *are* properly generated.

You can always do something like this to use ANTLR 3 and Gradle:

```
task generateWithANTLR3(type:Exec) { 
  commandLine = ['java', '-cp', 'antlr-3.2.jar', 'org.antlr.Tool', 'T.g']  
}
```

*(assuming the ANTLR jar and the grammar file are in the same dir as your Gradle build file)*

**EDIT**

And you can also let the `Tool` output the generated source files in a particular directory. The following task:

```
task generateWithANTLR3(type:Exec) { 
  commandLine = ['java', '-cp', 'antlr-3.2.jar', 'org.antlr.Tool', '-o', 'src/x/y/generated/', 'T.g']  
}
```

will put the generated files in `src/x/y/generated/`.

Comment: Thanks Bart (3 for 3 this week on answering my questions). I'm going to have a further explore on this, it's compiling in eclipse at moment, but I've designed the project around the gradle defaults to try and "harness the power" of gradle. It's nice to know I can fall back to an explicit Antlr3 task like this though.

Comment: It seems this is the only way to do it at the moment. There's a [pull request to add antlr3 support](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/pull/69) which is [discussed here](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/Antlr-v3-plugin-td5605784.html) but hasn't been pulled into main gradle yet. I'm just building gradle and am going to try out the plugin myself and might make some noise if it looks good.

Answer (score 5):

For completeness, I came up with the following gradle build file for my project which takes the version from [tapestryjava blogspot](http://tapestryjava.blogspot.co.uk/2011/03/combining-gradle-with-antlr3.html) and adds in some of the comments.

The only thing I need to change is not using dynamic properties to remove the warning.

```
apply plugin: 'java'

project.ext.grammarpackage = "eclipse"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    antlr3
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.antlr:antlr-runtime:3.2'
    antlr3 'org.antlr:antlr:3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}

task antlrOutputDir << {
    mkdir(generateGrammarSource.destinationDir)
}

task generateGrammarSource(dependsOn: antlrOutputDir, type: JavaExec) {
    description = 'Generates Java sources from Antlr3 grammars.'

    destinationDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources/antlr"
    def antlrSource = 'src/main/antlr'

    inputs.dir file(antlrSource)
    outputs.dir file(destinationDir)

    def grammars = fileTree(antlrSource).include('**/*.g')

    main = 'org.antlr.Tool'
    classpath = configurations.antlr3
    args = ["-o", "${destinationDir}/${project.ext.grammarpackage}", grammars.files].flatten()
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn generateGrammarSource
    source generateGrammarSource.destinationDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is mix of Mark Fisher and Bart Kiers response which is getting antlr jar from dependencies and put in classpath. It works for me:

```
configurations {
    antlr3
}

dependencies {
    antlr3 'org.antlr:antlr:3.4'
}


task generateWithANTLR3(type:Exec) { 
  commandLine = ['java', '-cp',  configurations.antlr3.getAsPath(), 'org.antlr.Tool', '-o', 'target/generated-sources/antlr3/t3', 'src/main/antlr3/t2/Exp.g']
}
```